# csv-parse is throwing Invalid Opening Quote: a quote is found inside a field at line

Tags: javascript, node-csv-parse

I know there are other posts out there but none of them seem to fix my issues. I am using csv-parse with node js. This is the CSV header and record that I'm trying to parse.

```
sku,description,productUnitOfMeasure,unitCost,retailPrice,wholesalePrice,dropShipPrice,assemblyCost,planner,comments,productId,fileUpdate,SkuStatus,Master Planning Family,Category,Sub-Category,Brand,ShortCode,Import/Domestic,Inventory Value,Master Pack Quantity,Pallet / TI / HI,40HC Quantity,Product Group ID
032406021945-GreenBay,TFAL B2080264 INIT TNS GRY SAUTE PN 8",EA,7.72,13.99,0.00,0.00,0,Whitney Ehlke-2307,,032406021945,2022-01-25,New,COOKWARE,OPENSTOCK,NONE,T-FAL,B2080264,Domestic,208.44,3,0/0/0,0,23
```

I have no control over this file. I just need to be able to parse it. You will see that there is a double quote at the end of the description: `TFal B2080264 INI TNS GRY SAUTE PN 8"`.

I need the double quote to stay there and for that to parse as one field. I keep getting this error:

> Invalid Opening Quote: a quote is found inside a field at line 2.

The quote is not an opening. It's technically a closing. But regardless, it will not parse.

This is currently my code:

```
const parser = fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(
    parse({ columns: true, relax_quotes: true, escape: '\\', ltrim: true, rtrim: true })
)
```

I have removed some of the params and tried others, to no avail. Any ideas??

Comment: In case it's not clear to readers, the `8"` is part of the product description and indicates that the sauté pan is 8 inches in diameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code works fine with the latest csv-parse version (5.0.4). Which version of the csv-parse package are you using? I ask because it [looks like](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv/commit/9fffd50762e10b3794883c6b3751ad209510f82e) the option may have been renamed from `relax` to `relax_quotes` only recently.

So, I think the solution is either:

1. upgrade to the latest csv-parse, and indicate `relax_quotes`, or
2. stay with your current version of csv-parse, and indicate `relax`

Just to be sure `relax_quotes` works with the current library, I tested the following code and it worked as expected:

```
const csv = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');

const parser = fs.createReadStream("70880341.csv").pipe(
  csv.parse({ columns: true, relax_quotes: true, escape: '\\', ltrim: true, rtrim: true })
)

const records = [];

parser.on('readable', function() {
  let record;
  while ((record = parser.read()) !== null) {
    records.push(record);
  }
});

parser.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err.message);
});

parser.on('end', function() {
  console.log(records);
});
```

Result:

```
[{
    sku: '032406021945-GreenBay',
    description: 'TFAL B2080264 INIT TNS GRY SAUTE PN 8"',
    productUnitOfMeasure: 'EA',
    ...
}]
```

Comment: I had already tried the code you have, but I was using the new relax-quotes param. Changing it to just relax worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that ltrim and rtrim did error with some records. Removing them has worked for all records so far.

Answer (score 4):

For me full error message was: `CsvError: Invalid Opening Quote: a quote is found on field 0 at line 1, value is "" (utf8 bom)`

And adding "bom: true" parameter for csv.parse - helped.

Comment: This was the solution for my scenario. With `relax_quotes` that would add quotes around my first column/header and I would have something like..

`{
'"ID"': 1,
Title: 'Title'
}`